# Does this htaccess contains any security risk?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been developing a content management system with php, mysql and etc. For clean url's or search engine friendly url's I use following htaccess content. I found the core part on internet and not sure does it contains any security risk. Htaccess coding seems complicated for me. Thanks.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(panel)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

"panel" is the folder that has exception for the rule. I use $_GET["q"] and explode func. via Php to retrieve url category segments.

Comment: If you don't trust the one source of information you're using, look for others offering similar advice to confirm (there's loads of htaccess rewrite advice here on SO). In general, yes, this is secure and it is the way it's done. I accept that it can be complex, but if you're going to write this kind if thing, it's important to understand what it's doing, because it can be really difficult to debug if you get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I think like you but I need modrewrite very rarely.